# Vanilla Javascript Document Write based on ScreenResize

Tags: javascript, window, resize

I would like to know why document.write is not working based on screen resize funciton. Following is the code. Can anyone give me an explanation on this. Thanks in Advance

```
detectDevice=()=>{
    let ww = window.innerWidth;
    if(ww>500) {
        document.write("Its Large Device");
    }
    else {
        document.write("Its Small Device");
    }
}
detectDevice();
window.addEventListener("resize", detectDevice);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is  using the wrong function:
`let ww = window.innerWidth;`
instead, use the following:

```
 let ww = screen.width;
```

Comment: I tried it, but not works.